# Is there a "$elemMatch" for consult text in a object (not array)?

Tags: python, database, mongodb

I have this object:

[image: My case]

I want to set all the values of "estado" to "false"

I try to use `$elemMatch` to find all the fields, and pass this as a filter to the `$set` method, but I think `$elemMatch` only works with arrays.

Comment: It is better to post your object details as text, not as image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've realized this, but while mongo doesn't have good operators to deal with nested objects with arbitrary keys, it does have great array operators that make it easy (and quick!) to update & deal with nested array documents. You can even create indexes that work on keys within arrays to make querying quicker.

Depending on how much your application code depends on this array structure, you might want to first transform your documents into arrays and then use https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/ to update your documents. To transform your documents, you can write a script in application code, write a script in the mongo shell in js, or use an aggregation pipeline with $out to write your documents to a new collection.

If updating your schema isn't feasible, I think you're going to have to write a script to change those nested document fields.